# How to get page permission by role

Tags: c#, kentico

Using Kentico 11.0.26 with MVC.
I need to find out the permissions on a page for a particular role. The API examples page only shows how to do it by user (not role).

https://docs.kentico.com/api11/content-management/page-security#Pagesecurity-Checkingpermissionsforspecificpages(ACLs)

EDIT: I'm trying to use it like this

```
foreach (CMS.DocumentEngine.NodePermissionsEnum permission in (CMS.DocumentEngine.NodePermissionsEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(CMS.DocumentEngine.NodePermissionsEnum)))
{
    DataSet dataSet = AclItemInfoProvider.GetAllowedRoles(page.NodeACLID, permission, "OperatorName,Allowed,Denied");
    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            string roleName = row[table.Columns[0]].ToString();
            string allowed = row[table.Columns[1]].ToString();
            string denied = row[table.Columns[2]].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Role: {0}: Permission: {1}, Allowed: {2}, Denied: {3}", roleName, permission, allowed, denied);
        }
    }
}
```

**Why does allowed have a value of 47, instead of 0 or 1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that, because there is only one field in DB which holds Allowed values, but there is several permissions like 'Read (0), Modify (1), Create (2), Delete (3)..', all of them are saved in one field as int value (with base 2 and exponent related to exact permission). In that case, when you retrieve value next time, you will know for sure which of those are selected because there is only one combination that gave exact number. To clarify this, each number bellow represent one permission (Read is 0, which means 2⁰ = 1, Modify is 2¹ = 2, Create is 2² = 4 ...) :

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 
+ + + + -  +   -  = 47
```

This means that for your current document you have allowed: Read, Modify, Create, Delete and ExploreTree permissions.

Same goes for Deny as well.

You can check which permissions are allowed with this peace of code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Parses permission value and return true if appropriate bit is 1.
    /// </summary>
    protected bool IsPermissionTrue(int permissionValue, NodePermissionsEnum permission)
    {
        return ((permissionValue >> Convert.ToInt32(permission)) % 2) == 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to test this, but it could be a bug. There is a bit shift inside API which is converting values returned by SP. You could give it a try to double check and submit it as a bug. However you could try retrieving role bound ACLItemInfo via object query:

```
var AclItems = AclItemInfoProvider.GetAclItems().WhereEquals(nameof(AclItemInfo.RoleID), 7)
```